# How do I use Spring Boot to serve static content located in Dropbox folder?

Tags: apache, spring-mvc, dropbox, static-content, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web application, and I would like to serve static content located in a shared Dropbox directory on my Linode VPS (~/Dropbox/images).  I've read that Spring Boot will automatically serve static content from

```
"classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
"classpath:/resources/",
"classpath:/static/",
"classpath:/public/",
```

but of course my Dropbox directory is not on the classpath.

Although I could configure Apache to serve the images in my Dropbox folder, I would like to take advantage of Spring Security to restrict access of the static content to authenticated users.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can add your own static resource handler (it overwrites the default), e.g.

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:/path/to/my/dropbox/");
    }
}
```

There is some documentation about this in [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content), but it's really just a vanilla Spring MVC feature.

Also since spring boot 1.2 (I think) you can simply set `spring.resources.staticLocations`.

Comment: I'm not finding the super class WebMvcAdapter in your example above. Which Spring JAR contains that class?

Comment: I extended WebMvcConfigurerAdapter instead.

Comment: As @kaliatech mentioned, don't forget the trailing slash on the Resource Location path.

Comment: To leave default resources mapping and add dropbbox folder as addition resources is recomended rename resourceHandler path, for sample: registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**").addResourceLocations("file:/path/to/my/dropbox/");

Comment: link for page not found. Since this is the accepted answer with a significant amount of votes may I suggest an update on this?

Comment: It even works for relative directory with "file:./dir/"

Comment: Make sure that the `addResourceLocations` paths ends with `/`, otherwise, it causes 404

Comment: FYI this has at least one caveat: it will not map `/` to `/index.html`
WelcomePageHandlerMapping uses `resource.static-locations` so it's harder to simulate via code.

Comment: Is this still the best way to do this in 2020? Given "WebMvcConfigurerAdapter" is deprecated in newer versions of spring.

Comment: `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` was only deprecated in favour of its interface (read the javadocs). So it's the same.

Answer (score 35):

Springboot (via Spring) now makes adding to existing resource handlers easy. See [Dave Syers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21124562/123378).  To add to the existing static resource handlers, simply be sure to use a resource handler path that doesn't override existing paths.

The two "also" notes below are still valid.

.
.
.

***[Edit: The approach below is no longer valid]***

If you want to *extend* the default static resource handlers, then something like this seems to work:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
public class CustomWebMvcAutoConfig extends
                    WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    String myExternalFilePath = "file:///C:/Temp/whatever/m/";

    registry.addResourceHandler("/m/**").addResourceLocations(myExternalFilePath);

    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
  }

}
```

The call to `super.addResourceHandlers` sets up the default handlers.

Also:

- Note the trailing slash on the external file path. (Depends on your expectation for URL mappings).
- Consider reviewing the source code of [WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this!  I'd also mention that it's important to include the trailing /** on the resource handler mapping as well, I forgot to add that and I kept getting 404 errors

Comment: This solution goes in the right direction, however it's not possible to inherit from WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter because the constructor arguments are not all public.

Comment: @GeoffroyWarin This answer was originally written for older versions. I edited it just now to indicate that. See Dave Syer's answer. To add to existing resource handlers simply be sure not to override existing resource paths.

Answer (score 21):

Based on @Dave Syers answer I add the following class to my  Spring Boot project:

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StaticResourceConfiguration.class);

 @Value("${static.path}")
 private String staticPath;

 @Override
 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    if(staticPath != null) {
        LOG.info("Serving static content from " + staticPath);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:" + staticPath);
    }
 }

 // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381781/java-spring-boot-how-to-map-my-my-app-root-to-index-html
 @Override
 public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/index.html");
 }
}
```

This allows me to start my spring boot app with the parameter `--static.path` like

```
java -jar spring-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --static.path=/path/to/my/static-files/
```

This can be very handy for development and testing.

Comment: Is there a way use 'index.html' instead of '/' directly without redirecting?

Answer (score 10):

There's a property `spring.resources.staticLocations` that can be set in the `application.properties`. Note that this will override the default locations. See `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ResourceProperties`.

Comment: `spring.resources.staticLocations` is deprecated, but you can use  `spring.web.resources.staticLocations` instead.

Answer (score 10):

Based on @Dave Syer, @kaliatech and @asmaier answers the springboot v2+ way would be:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
public class StaticResourceConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer  {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    String myExternalFilePath = "file:///C:/temp/whatever/m/";

     registry.addResourceHandler("/m/**").addResourceLocations(myExternalFilePath);

  }

}
```

Comment: `@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)` adding this saved my day. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

- OS: Win 10
- Spring Boot: 2.1.2

I wanted to serve static content from c:/images

Adding this property worked for me:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/,file:///C:/images/
```

I found the original value of the property in the Spring Boot Doc [Appendix A](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

This will make c:/images/image.jpg to be accessible as http://localhost:8080/image.jpg

Comment: `spring.resources.static-locations` is deprecated, but you can use  `spring.web.resources.static-locations` instead.

Comment: is it not spring.web.resources.static-locations instead of spring.resources.static-locations?

Answer (score 8):

@Mark Schäfer

Never too late, but add a slash (`/`) after static:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:/opt/x/y/z/static/
```

So `http://<host>/index.html` is now reachable.

Answer (score 2):

To serve from file system

I added `spring.resources.static-location=file:../frontend/build` in `application.properties`

`index.html` is present in the `build` folder

Use can also add absolute path

`spring.resources.static-location=file:/User/XYZ/Desktop/frontend/build`

I think similarly you can try adding Dropbox folder path.

Answer (score 1):

For the current Spring-Boot Version 1.5.3 the parameter is

`spring.resources.static-locations`

**Update**
I configured

`spring.resources.static-locations=file:/opt/x/y/z/static``

and expected to get my index.html living in this folder when calling

`http://<host>/index.html`

This did not work. I had to include the *folder name* in the URL:

`http://<host>/static/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I didn't have any success with the `spring.resources.static-locations` recommended above; what worked for me was setting spring.thymeleaf.prefix:

```
report.location=file:/Users/bill/report/html/
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=${report.location}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated now (see [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552835/the-type-webmvcconfigureradapter-is-deprecated/47553586)). Due to Java 8 default methods, you only have to implement [WebMvcConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can place your folder in the root of the ServletContext.

Then specify a relative or absolute path to this directory in application.yml:

```
spring:
  resources:
    static-locations: file:some_temp_files/
```

The resources in this folder will be available (for downloading, for example) at:

```
http://<host>:<port>/<context>/your_file.csv
```