# Java Spring Boot: How to map my app root (“/”) to index.html?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I map my app root `http://localhost:8080/` to a static `index.html`?
If I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/index.html` its works fine.

My app structure is :

[image: dirs]

My `config\WebConfig.java` looks like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
  }
}
```

I tried to add `registry.addResourceHandler("/").addResourceLocations("/index.html");` but it fails.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/spring-boot-context-root

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski It shows how to map `http://localhost:8080/appName` but its not what I need...

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated

Answer (score 182, accepted):

It would have worked out of the box if you hadn't used `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. When you do that you switch off all the things that Spring Boot does for you in `WebMvcAutoConfiguration`. You could remove that annotation, or you could add back the view controller that you switched off (in your `WebMvcConfigurer`):

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
}
```

With more recent Spring Boot versions (3.2.3 or above) you can still do the above, but there is an alternative which is recommended by the Spring MVC developers, which is to use a `@Bean` of type `RouterFunction`. For example:

```
static import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.RequestPredicates.path;
...
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> spaRouter() {
    ClassPathResource index = new ClassPathResource("static/index.html");
    return route().resource(path("/"), index).build();
}
```

That's a really simple example, fixing a problem that didn't exist (OP erased autoconfiguration that already covered it). A more realistic example would be something like this:

```
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.path;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.pathExtension;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions.route;
// ...
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> spaRouter() {
    ClassPathResource index = new ClassPathResource("static/index.html");
    List<String> extensions = Arrays.asList("js", "css", "ico", "png", "jpg", "gif");
    RequestPredicate spaPredicate = path("/api/**").or(path("/error")).or(pathExtension(extensions::contains)).negate();
    return route().resource(spaPredicate, index).build();;
}
```

It filters out requests for api or error output, and also for common static filenames, and directs all other requests that are not handled elsewhere to the home page. That's a common scenario that isn't handled by autoconfiguration.

Comment: Thanks.. I didn't realised that... couldn't find one simple demo in their site that shows that...

Comment: From [the reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration): "If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features, and you just want to add additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view controllers etc.) you can add your own @Bean of type `WebMvcConfigurerAdapte`r, but without `@EnableWebMvc`"

Comment: This will serve `index.html` at `/` . But is it possible to also make the browser actually change the url from `/` to `/index.html` ?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. In case you also want to change the url from `/` to `/index.html` use `"redirect:/index.html"`  instead of forward.

Comment: I am not using the @EnableWebMvc annotation, and I do not get redirected to index.html.

Comment: You might as well try **redirect:/index.html**. *forward* did not work for me. Also, if using spring-boot, you might simply want to `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` from your `@Configuration` class, and override `addViewControllers`. No need to add a `@Bean` explicit.

Comment: My spring boot app root url http://host:port/contextpath was not taking me to the index.html but showed "full authentication is required". I didn't do these changes but added security.ignored="/" to make it work. My app is secured with spring security oauth2, Am I doing this right by adding root to security.ignored?

Comment: @DaveSyer is there a difference in declare that `addViewControllers` method through `@Configuration` + `WebMvcConfigurer`'s `addViewControllers` implementation (your approach) **vs**  `@Configuration` + `@Bean` such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/31235990/3665178 ? (based in your previous comment) - Just curious when the latter would be mandatory

Comment: @DaveSyer the content shared in your comment about the Reference Documentation does not include anymore the _you can add your own @Bean of type_ part. Why was removed that `@Bean` approach?

Comment: It's still there (but the type changed to `WebMvcConfigurer`)

Answer (score 45):

An example of Dave Syer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27383522/3665178) and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381781/java-spring-boot-how-to-map-my-app-root-to-index-html#comment43242465_27383522):

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MyWebMvcConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter forwardToIndex() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
                // forward requests to /admin and /user to their index.html
                registry.addViewController("/admin").setViewName(
                        "forward:/admin/index.html");
                registry.addViewController("/user").setViewName(
                        "forward:/user/index.html");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Use WebMvcConfigurer instead of deprecated WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in Spring 5.

Answer (score 35):

if it is a Spring boot App.

Spring Boot automatically detects index.html in public/static/webapp folder. If you have written any controller `@Requestmapping("/")` it will override the default feature and it will not show the `index.html` unless you type `localhost:8080/index.html`

Comment: I created a src/main/resources/public/index.html file and it worked! Thanks

Comment: Is that still true?

Comment: Still true as of today

Comment: oh yes, my colleague added a meaningless @Requestmapping("/") somewhere. Thanks for pointing that out. Now welcome page works now.

Answer (score 24):

If you use the latest `spring-boot 2.1.6.RELEASE` with a simple `@RestController` annotation then you do not need to do anything, just add your `index.html` file under the `resources/static` folder:

```
project
  ├── src
      ├── main
          └── resources
              └── static
                  └── index.html
```

Then hit the root URL of your app http://localhost:8080.

The solution above works out of the box with Spring and Tomcat and your HTTP request to the root `/`  is mapped automatically to the `index.html` file. But if you used `@EnableWebMvc` annotation then you switch off that Spring Boot does for you. In this case, you have two options:

**(1)** remove that annotation

**(2)** or you could add back the view controller that you switched off

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
   }
   
}
```

Hope that it will help everyone.

Comment: in my case, it was working but when I changed from tomcat to Undertow suddenly stop working. now i need a way to forward / to my index.html

Comment: Updated the post above with the solution that can help you.

Answer (score 18):

```
@Configuration  
@EnableWebMvc  
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "index.html");
    }

}
```

Comment: meanwhile is WebMvcConfigurerAdapter deprecated

Answer (score 13):

Update: Jan-2019

First create public folder under resources and create index.html file.
Use WebMvcConfigurer instead of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }

}
```

Comment: what could be wrong if this does not work? resources/public/index.html exists; java 13; spring 2.2.2; tomcat

Answer (score 7):

You can add a RedirectViewController like:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "/index.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Inside `Spring Boot`, I always put the webpages inside a folder like `public` or `webapps` or `views` and place it inside `src/main/resources` directory as you can see in `application.properties` also.

[image: Spring_Boot-Project-Explorer-View]

and this is my `application.properties`:

```
server.port=15800
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/public/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

as soon you put the url like `servername:15800` and this request received by Spring Boot occupied Servlet dispatcher it will exactly search the `index.html` and this name will in case sensitive as the `spring.mvc.view.suffix` which would be html, jsp, htm etc.

Hope it would help manyone.

Comment: @ArifMustafa In recent Sprint Boot versions, I recommend to put webpages inside templates also.

Comment: Do you have references for that? I'm trying to create a react/redux frontend project with a Spring backend and I'm not sure about the best practices involved.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Spring boot knows where static html files are located.

1. Add index.html into resources/static folder
2. Then delete full controller method for root path like @RequestMapping("/") etc
3. Run app and check http://localhost:8080 (Should work)

Comment: Finally your answer worked :)

Answer (score 3):

1. index.html file should come under below location - 
      src/resources/public/index.html OR
      src/resources/static/index.html
   if both location defined then which first occur index.html will call from that directory.
2. The source code looks like -

   ```
   package com.bluestone.pms.app.boot; 
   import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
   import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
   import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;



   @SpringBootApplication 
   @EnableAutoConfiguration
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.your.pkg"}) 
   public class BootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {



   /**
    * @param args Arguments
   */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(BootApplication.class);
   /* Setting Boot banner off default value is true */
   application.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
   application.run(args);
   }

   /**
     * @param builder a builder for the application context
     * @return the application builder
     * @see SpringApplicationBuilder
    */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
     builder) {
       return super.configure(builder);
      }
   }
   ```