# How does the JHipster/Angular configuration determines that it needs to use the index.html file?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, jhipster

I have just generated an Spring/Angular app using JHipster.

I successfully accessed the home page by using this URL: `http://localhost:8080` which redirects to `http://localhost:8080/#/` and the `index.html` file is loaded properly.

I am not sure how Angular and the browser determine that they need to load the **`index.html`** file.

Where is this configured in a JHipster app?

**edit**: Is there some *"default home page"* configuration somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I successfully accessed the home page by using this URL:
>   http://localhost:8080 which redirects to http://localhost:8080/#/

The request to the server is for "/" and index.html is served.  The "/#/" is all client side stuff (Angular routing) that happens when the javascript on the index.html page fires up, not the result of a server side redirect.

> Where is this configured in a JHipster app?

This is a Spring Boot default, not something specific to JHipster.  From the [Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration):

> The auto-configuration adds the following features on top of Spring’s
>   defaults:
>
> - Static index.html support.
>
> By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory
>   called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in
>   the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext. It uses the
>   ResourceHttpRequestHandler from Spring MVC so you can modify that
>   behavior by adding your own WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and overriding the
>   addResourceHandlers method.

I don't think this is configurable through a property file or something similar, you'll have to write some code.  See the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381781/java-spring-boot-how-to-map-my-my-app-root-to-index-html).

Comment: Thanks ever so much John!

Comment: The relevant code can be found in class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration`.