# Spring-boot lose default index.html redirect when changing server.servlet.path

Tags: spring-boot

I've lost the automatic forward to index.html enabled by `spring-boot-starter-web` since I changed the `server.servlet.path=/spring` to have acuators endpoints under /spring.

I have a pure REST API app,  I'm using Jersey for my endpoints `@ApplicationPath("/user)`, but I want to use the default / context to redirect to index.html for an API documentation.

I've tried the solution indicated in [Java Spring Boot: How to map my app root (“/”) to index.html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381781/java-spring-boot-how-to-map-my-app-root-to-index-html) but to no avail:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter forwardToIndex() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            // redirect requests to / to index.html
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/index.html");
        }
    };
}
```

Is it possible to enable it ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're not serving `/` at all now. Since your change, Spring Boot only handles whatever comes at `/spring`.

That code of yours is actually asking `/spring/` to redirect to `/spring/index.html`.

Comment: Isn't there anyway to dedicate a namespace to Acuator services while continuing serving the default context (and other context)?

Comment: You're looking for [`management.context-path`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-management-server-context-path). What you've changed is the root servlet.