# Spring Boot - how to serve one static html file for multiple routes in specified root

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I need to serve static `html` file `(/src/main/resources/static/folder/index.html)` for all routes in specified root `(as example '/main/\**')`. I've tried to annotate controller method with `@RequestMapping("/main/**")`, but it works only for `'/main'` route, not for '`/main/foo'`, `'/main/foo/bar'`, etc...

So, how i can do this in spring boot?

Comment: It is done by adding a view controller, as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381781/java-spring-boot-how-to-map-my-app-root-to-index-html. according to the spring javadoc  documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ViewControllerRegistry.html#addViewController-java.lang.String- you can either map from a concrete path or from a pattern, which is what you need.

Comment: thats odd, it seems to be working for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
// application.properties
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html


// Controller for index.html
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping({"/login", "/main/**"})
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, in addition just wanted to throw in I annotated the other main Application Class with @SpringBootApplication and put my static angular app in the resources\public folder

Answer (score 1):

You have to add / edit a Configuration object.

Here is our way to do it:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public static final String INDEX_VIEW_NAME = "forward:index.html";



    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName(INDEX_VIEW_NAME);
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName(INDEX_VIEW_NAME);
        registry.addViewController("/logout").setViewName(INDEX_VIEW_NAME);
    }
}
```