# Spring Boot resource handler patterns for single page applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, single-page-application, static-files

I have the following in my Spring Boot configuration:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
            .addResourceHandler("**/*.*")
            .addResourceLocations("file:static/");
}
```

Since I'm creating a single page app I want this resource handler to deliver static files if the following is true:

- URL does not start with */api*
- This resource handler contains a file that matches the path from the URL

If there are no matching file, the resource handler **should not respond with 404** but let the call through to the controllers of the project.

In one of them I place my fallback to index.html annotation (again unless the URL starts with /api):

```
@GetMapping({"/**", "/"})
```

This last part works fine but the problem is that the resource handler returns a 404 if there are no matching files instead of letting the call through (I'm used to the middleware patterns of Node.js and Go) to the controllers. How can I achieve this? Can I create my own resource handler that acts more middleware like?

In Go with Echo for example you just need to enable HTML5 with a skipper function for /api:

```
func main() {
    server := echo.New()

    server.Use(middleware.Static("static"))
    server.Use(middleware.StaticWithConfig(middleware.StaticConfig{
        Root:    "static",
        HTML5:   true,
        Skipper: noHTML5IfAPICallSkipper,
    }))

    server.Logger.Fatal(server.Start(":1323"))
}

func noHTML5IfAPICallSkipper(context echo.Context) bool {
    if strings.HasPrefix(context.Path(), "/api/") {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

How to enable this single page app routing patterns in Spring Boot?

Oh, and by the way, it's crucial that the static files are served from disk rather than from a classpath or anything else that is packaged inside a jar. This service will run with Docker and it has to be possible to mount the files from outside the container.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47427729/1032167 probably similar, i ended up using approach with custom `ResourceResolver`. You can specify any location you want to in this custom `ResourceResolver`: file or classpath. It is just a direction for you to look at, because the link answer  never passes anything to the controller and returns index page pretty much for every request except static files/api/custom controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
public class Application  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { // or implements WebMvcConfigurer (Spring Boot 2)

    @Value("${static.path}")
    private String staticPath;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*.*").addResourceLocations("file:"+staticPath);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("/index.html");
    }

    ...
}
```

You must to add to application.properties file the line:

```
`static.path=path/to/static/content`
```

If you want to use Docker, this path need to reference to internal docker container directory, an example: `/opt/app/statics` and then, map the external path to this:

You must to add to application.properties file the line: `static.path=/opt/app/statics`

And execute docker like this:

`docker run ... -v /absolute/static/path/at/host:/opt/app/statics image:version`