# Spring Boot .html files not resolving

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app -

I have a controller -

```
@Controller("CWOController")
@RequestMapping(value = "/cworequest")
public class CWOController {


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/index.html"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String getCwoIdSearchForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("cwoRequestForm", new CWORequest());
        return "index";
    }
```

This works on the url -> http://localhost:8080/cworequest/

but I need -> http://localhost:8080/cworequest/index.html to map to the above GET.

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you please look into following link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381781/java-spring-boot-how-to-map-my-app-root-to-index-html

Comment: Thanks Praddep...Sorry i had the wrong mapping.  Here is what it looks like.

@RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
 public String getCwoIdSearchForm(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("cwoRequestForm", new CWORequest());
  return "index";
 }

Comment: Now you were able to resolve or not?

Answer (score 0):

Add another default method with mapping / and return error or anything else.