# Java Spring Boot: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a Spring Boot application to serve a single file, "index.html", for my AngularJS application. I have the following classes:

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
        extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**BaseController.java**

```
@Controller
public class BaseController
{
    // Map all urls to this method aside from ones starting with api
    @RequestMapping(value = "/**")
    public String getIndexHtml()
    {
        System.out.println("hi me");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**MvcConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration
        extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

And the following directory structure:

```
src
 └── main
     ├── java
     │   └── com
     │       └── myangularapp
     │           ├── Application.java
     │           ├── config
     │           │   └── MvcConfiguration.java
     │           └── controllers
     │               └── BaseController.java
     └── webapp
         └── WEB-INF
             └── index.html
```

I then have gradle create the application into a war before deploying on tomcat 8.

However, any time I try and visit the website, I always see this page: [image]

And the following stack trace:

```
2017-07-15 00:01:51.551 ERROR 42496 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.5.0.[dispatcherServlet]  : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:231) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:594) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:231) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
```

Which eventually turns into:

```
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:231) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:594) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getSessionId(WebUtils.java:288) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1077) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

------------------------**Update**------------------------

Off the back of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27383522/2489463), I did not have `@EnableWebMvc` on my MvcConfiguration class. I added it in, and the view was resolved and everything started working.