# Add Static resources in spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am a newbie to spring boot architecture. It says that to let the index pages to find static resources like js, we need to keep it under "src/main/resources/static".

Directory Structure:

Html files: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/

js files: src/main/resources/static/js/

This is my index page:

```
<html ng-app="RollbackApp">

<head>
    <title>My Rollback View</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="rollbackController"><p>
    <button ng-click="rollback()">RollBack</button>
</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Currently the index page is not able to load my "app.js"

My Mvc config class is as follows:

```
package com.manoj;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

/**
 * Created by manojma on 10/13/2017.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

I am unable to find the reason, why it is not able to find my js files.

Please help me with this.!!

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you create your own `ApplicationWebMvcConfig` if Spring boot already has one? If you want to customize the prefix/suffix for those JSPs, you can use the `spring.mvc.view.prefix` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix` properties. And even more questionable is why you're using JSPs when you're not using any JSP related stuff and even named the suffix `*.html`.

Comment: Adding spring.mvc.view.prefix in application.properties is not solving my problem. .So I searched around and found this solution and this is perfectly running for me.. But the problem is it is not able to find js files.. Is there any method in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  to add resources like js files.

Comment: Regarding the question of "Why I am using Jsps", there is a requirement to use spring boot and I am finding a way to use it with angularjs as the view of application is rendered using angularjs

Comment: That's exactly why I was asking, you can also put your `index.html` in the `src/main/resources/static` folder as well and it will be served like JavaScript. Unless you're going to use serverside rendering (you're using AngularJS, so probably not), you don't actually need JSP and could remove that complexity entirely from your application.

Comment: I need to set index.html as the starting page and keeping index.html in resources/static folder in such case, is not helping.

Comment: `index.html` is already the default welcome page within Spring boot. But you can also configure this, as you can see in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381781/java-spring-boot-how-to-map-my-app-root-to-index-html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your resource handler isn't configured correctly. You've set `/resources/static/` as your resource location. However, considering that `src/main/resources` is put entirely on your classpath, you should leave away the `/resources` part. Additionally, you should mention that you're looking on your classpath, so you should probably use `classpath:/static/`.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
}
```

Additionally to that, you've defined the resource handler to forward requests starting from `/resources/**`. That means that if you relatively request `js/app.js`, it won't work, since it won't trigger the resource handler. You need to use `resources/js/app.js`:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/app.js"></script>
```

---

However, if your goal is to just statically serve some HTML pages, it's a lot easier to just put the HTML pages into the `src/main/resources/static` folder as well. Spring boot already serves the `index.html` by default as [the welcome page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/cd316e7f3d492201e858c1dd6602a1d4e349f4b2/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L523-L529) but it [can be customized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381781/java-spring-boot-how-to-map-my-app-root-to-index-html).

Answer (score 0):

you have to be careful of overriding any of the defaults

I struggled with connecting my static resources to my jsp pages and this is what I finally used to get it working with Spring boot 2.0. You can see my properties and also what the urls look like when mapping to static resources like images or plain html.

Next we need to define the template prefix and suffix for our JSP files in **application.properties**. Thus add:  (the context path 'pdx' is optional and you can pick a name to match your application)

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.servlet.context-path=/pdx
```

http://localhost:8080/pdx/images/thedocks.jpg access static resources in *src/main/resources/static/images/thedocks.jpg*

http://localhost:8080/pdx/ loads index.html in s*rc/main/resources/static/index.html*

http://localhost:8080/pdx/css/home.css loads css class in s*rc/main/resources/static/css/home.css*

http://localhost:8080/pdx/h loads my home controller with @Controller("/") and @GetRequest(“/h”) annotations.

my jsp page loads the static image like this

```
<img alt="the docks" src="/pdx/images/thedocks.jpg"/>
```