# Mapping Application Root (/) to default landing page (index.jsp) in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring Boot and I know that this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381781/java-spring-boot-how-to-map-my-app-root-to-index-html), but none of the answers could be of any help to me. I googled and found [this](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-index-page-example/) link but this too didn't work (I don't want to set it by mapping root context in controller). So I am asking here once again, **How to map the welcome page or default page(index.jsp) to the root context in Spring Boot application?**

This is my project structure and I am using Spring Boot 2.0.3

[image]

Even when I explicitly provide the complete path, it remains unfound as shown below. Please help me understand what am I missing here.
[image]

Comment: The correct solutions don't work because you are using JSPs (whereas those use Thymeleaf or a static `index.html`) and second those JSPs are in the wrong location. I would however strongly reconsider the use of JSP with Spring Boot as those are quite restrictive when using embedded containers.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the suggestion but what would be the way to go ahead if I want to continue with JSPs.

Comment: Follow the regular war creation and place the JSPs in the proper location (and configure the view resolver as such) . But as stated you should really consider other options as those are much more flexible in an embedded world.