# Java: How to load an HTML page with Spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I try to load the index.html using Spring. But when I load it in localhost instead of getting my HTML page I just get a string that says index.

[My Resource structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEJlG.png)

I try to load the index with the IndexController

```
    @Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String welcome() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381781/java-spring-boot-how-to-map-my-app-root-to-index-html

Comment: https://www.javaboss.it/servire-pagine-jsp-con-spring-boot-e-spring-mvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make 2 changes.

1. Remove `@ResponseBody` as it will send response in body instead of a view page.
2. There is a typo in folder name there. Rename your folder name with **templates** instead of templetes.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Removed the @ResponseBody and fixed the spelling error.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the @ResponseBody annotation on the method. It tells Spring that the return value of the method should be serialized and sent to the client, rather than Spring treating the string as a view name.

Comment: I removed the @ResponseBody and now got:

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [index], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers error

Answer (score -1):

Try with RedirectView :

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public RedirectView welcome() {
        //@FIXME load url from propertie
        return new RedirectView("http://localhost/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above and now when I connect to localhost it redirects to http://localhost/index.html and I get an Unable to connect from the browser.

Comment: replace  localhost/index.html  with your working index, i dont know your port and the frontpage tecnology.