# Spring Boot : Assign the file path to a variable

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am assigning a absolute path for a variable in my spring boot application but it is not getting picked up as I am getting a null pointer exception

```
private static final String TESTCASE_DIR = "/resources/static/bpmtestconfig/config/testcase/";
```

Answer (score 0):

configure in spring xml file as

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

it may work for you

Comment: Sam, I am not using any spring xml as spring boot automatically resolves the things and by default it will take "/" separator

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123437/how-do-i-use-spring-boot-to-serve-static-content-located-in-dropbox-folder