# Spring boot serving static resource - sitemap.xml

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I work on spring boot 1.3.3.RELEASE with  JSP as view technology.

JSP pages , static resources like CSS, JS and images are loading properly. But how to serve static resource like txt or xml (robots.txt, sitemap.xml)

My controller is handling the request and trying to render jsp view.

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleWebJspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SampleWebJspApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleWebJspApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}")
    public String welcome(@PathVariable String name) {       
        return name;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Following URL's handled by controller and it renders home.jsp

```
/home  
/home.css
/home.js
/home.txt 
/home.xml
```

Following URL's Not working

```
/home.jsp - 404 
/robots.txt - 404 - trying to render robots.jsp
/sitemap.xml - 404 - trying to render sitemap.jsp
```

Comment: You have designed your controller to handle those URLs and now you are surprised that it behaves the way you designed it to behave?

Answer (score 1):

Spring-Boot doesnt do jsp's anymore, they are trying to force you to use thymeleaf or another templating engine, static resources are available from certain directories.  /static is one of them. and the thymeleaf files need to be in a templates folder.

My setup on my latest spring boot is as follows

> application/src/main/resources/static
>
> ```
>                           /templates
>
>                           application.properties
> ```

for other ones you need to add a resourcehandler for the other locations /robots.txt etc

Comment: I have robotx.txt and sitemap.xml under static folder. But still it tries to load *.jsp . But strange it does not handle *.jsp

Comment: If you can contact me on github i can let you have access to my working repo and you can see all the config without sharing it over the internets to the world + dog, github name is theresajayne

Comment: Is it possible to message a user in Git. ?  I don't see any option. apart from following and creating issue and pull request.

Comment: well i use theresajayne everywhere else, discord, facebook etc. my gmail is tjforste70@gmail.com, are you Mugundan?

Answer (score 0):

Jsp still works with spring boot.

Not sure if you already did this but its important that you add these dependencies to your maven or gradle.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I already have those dependency and  JSP is working. problem in serving  static resource like text file or xml file .

Comment: Then, Theresa might be right about some limitations . See the official note about restrictions. it says:  JSPs should be avoided if possible, there are several known limitations when using them with embedded servlet containers. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations .  It doesnt states anything about static resources of type txt or xml.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured the Spring's View Resolver with this line `spring.mvc.view.prefix` , so every response returned by your controllers , will be chained to the view Resolver , which will try to find the resource under `/WEB_INF/JSP` based on the string name you returned(not sure if you have placed this folder under resources , as your app is a spring boot one , not a java web app). In order to do that and keep the view resolver , either wire up another servlet to share static resources or wire up a ResourcesController with default locations. Something like :

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/myStaticResources/", "classpath:/static/" };

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}
}
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123437/how-do-i-use-spring-boot-to-serve-static-content-located-in-dropbox-folder)

Also Spring boot gives you this way as well :

`spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/`

More info about the application properties [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)