# Setup springboot to display image

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I have a rest application who use spring boot 1.4.2 with tomcat embedded

On client side, user can take picture via webcam and save it to the server.

In the server side, i save img in example : /home/test/img/

In my web application what i need to setup to be able to display image?

```
<img src="paul.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to redefine the `spring.resources.static-locations` property, for instance:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/,file:/home/test/img/
```

Comment: No, it won't. if they use other directories (such as ` public` they need to specify that as well).

Comment: seem like we can read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123437/how-do-i-use-spring-boot-to-serve-static-content-located-in-dropbox-folder that do a replace... not a extend..

Comment: Yes but if you know where your resources are it's really the same thing. It's a matter of taste, really.