# How to config the Spring mvc static resource mapping configuration:<mvc:resources mapping.../> in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to develop web app with spring boot and i want to address my javascript and css resources in jsp files. 
i config my access to this files from jsp in dispatcher-servlet.xml like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
```

and in my jsp file i can use below code to access that:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
 <img class="first-slide home-image" src="<spring:url value="/resources/images/back1.jpg"/>" alt="First slide">
```

how i do config mvc:resources mapping in spring boot?

Comment: Sorry; it's not really clear what you're asking. What do you expect to be happening, and what is actually happening?

Comment: Why would you use Spring Boot with XML and JSP? Please no.

Comment: I do not use xml. I developing web app and need jsp.

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).

> By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory
> called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in
> the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext.

Also you can use Java config that is the same as the xml that you posted. Just override the `addResourceHandlers` method of `@Configuration` class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

A good blog post about Spring resources - [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources).

**Update:**

1. Note that for Spring boot 2.0.5 or later, `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated. Instead we can `implements WebMvcConfigurer`.
2. Note that for windows, we should pass string param to the `addResourceLocations` method like this:
   `.addResourceLocations("file:///D:/beijing_pic_sample/")`
3. A related thread can be found here: [How do I use Spring Boot to serve static content located in Dropbox folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123437/how-do-i-use-spring-boot-to-serve-static-content-located-in-dropbox-folder)

Comment: So do I need to `@Configuration` my DemoApplication class which is generated by the Spring boot framework, and then make it extending the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` by overriding the `addResourceHandlers` method?

Comment: @ZhaoGang I would suggest to create another Class in the same package as DemoApplication, e.g. `WebConfig` that is annotated with `@Configuration`, extends  `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, etc. Your `DemoApplication` is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` which extends `@Configuration`, so you can reuse that class as well, but in future you may have to add other configs that extend other Configurer Adapters...