# How to "display" files from external folder with spring boot 2.1.1

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm learning spring boot vs 2.1.1

I would like to display in the template image from an external folder.

There is the app structure in tomcat 9:

```
|-webApp/ws-app     // where ws-app is the running app
|
|-webData           // where I would like to get the image to display in template
```

I've read many article from 5 years ago and I've tried to used them without success.
Like this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123437/how-do-i-use-spring-boot-to-serve-static-content-located-in-dropbox-folder)

I've tried to add in application.properties this code:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:///C:/TMP/webData/images
```

Access it from the template like this:

```
http://localhost:8100/ws-app/img.jpg
```

I get 404 error

I've tried this coding too by creating a class like this :

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;


@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
public class CustomWebMvcAutoConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    String myExternalFilePath = "file:///C:/TMP/webData/images";

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations(myExternalFilePath);
    }
}
```

The same error 404

Someone can help me to understand what I'm doing wrong or give me the correct way if what I'm trying to do is obsolete ?

Thanks so much

Comment: if you register your handler to `/images/**` then you should access them via `/images/` like `http://localhost:8100/ws-app/ìmages/img.jpg`

Comment: how am i doing it ?

Comment: `<img src="/images/img.jpg" />` points to `C:/TMP/webData/images/img.png`

Comment: So the code I wrote is correct and should work ?

Comment: it should, but it does not need `@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)`

Comment: I took it off and it doesn't make any difference. To see where I did a mistake, I just add a class with the code, is there more config to do in spring boot to make it working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should end your external-file-path with a `/`

you do not need to add `@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)`

use `http://localhost:8100/ws-app/images/img.jpg` to access image if your image is stored as `C:/TMP/webData/images/img.jpg`

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebMvcAutoConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    String myExternalFilePath = "file:C:/TMP/webData/images/"; // end your path with a /

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations(myExternalFilePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so so much! With the correction of the myExternalFilePath, plus the port 8080 and not 8100 as I wrote (my bad) it works well