# Image doesn't load from external folder, Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Employees should be able to upload their profile picture, and that profile picture should be shown in the employee_info page. I was following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Xf_fbKQit8
Uploading picture is working, but I can't bring image to web page.

My pictures are in a folder outside of Spring Boot project. I've tried this configuration:

[How to "display" files from external folder with spring boot 2.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289571/how-to-display-files-from-external-folder-with-spring-boot-2-1-1)

My ConfigMVC class that implements WebMvcConfigurer:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {   
        String employeeProfileUploadPath = "file:C:/my_company/profile_pictures/";
        
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations(employeeProfileUploadPath);
    }
```

Like in video tutorial, I'm passing URL of image via method in my DTO class for employees:

```
@Transient
public String getPhotoImagePath()
{
    if(photo == null || nickname == null)
        return null;
    
    return "/my_company/profile_pictures/" + nickname + "/" + photo;
}
```

In controller I passed object of type EmployeeDTO to Model:

```
    MyCompanyUserDetails userDetails = (MyCompanyUserDetails)principal;
    int employeeId = userDetails.getEmployeeId();
    Optional<EmployeeDTO> optional = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId);
    EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = optional.get();
    model.addAttribute("employeeDTO", employeeDTO);
```

And in html with Thymeleaf:

```
<img th:src="@{${employeeDTO.photoImagePath}}" width = "180" height = "180">
```

Thymeleaf placed URL:

```
 http://localhost:8080/my_company/profile_pictures/admin1/admin1.jpg
```

Which is the right location of my image in my pc. I don't want to store it in ../static/images/** in Spring Boot project, I want this way and I've done MVC configuration as you could see above. I don't see what is the problem, but on Google Chrome console I get 404 error, resource not found.

Comment: If you paste your image URL into the chrome address bar does it work?

Comment: @HopeyOne no, I get 404 error

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using is not correct. The path should be something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/{appname}/images/admin1/admin1.jpg
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to include external folder, I tried to do configuration like Dirk Deyne's answer in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289571/how-to-display-files-from-external-folder-with-spring-boot-2-1-1
As I understood, if I do like this (which is similar from youtube video), link will be as you descibred, and picture won't be really in {appname}/images. But it's not working

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, have you tried to run your server and browse directly to your image in `C:/my_company/profile_pictures/` with the URL `http://localhost:8080/{appname}/images/admin1/admin1.jpg`? If you can figure out the URL where the server is serving your images, then you can put this in your thymeleaf page.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear with too much information. Allow me to summarize:
1. images are served from /static/images folder in Spring Boot by deafult (correct me if I'm wrong, I don't have much experience)
2. I want my images to be in a different place, for example C:/my_company/...
3. In order to include that location as well, I tried to configure WebMvcConfigurer interface, just like Dirk Deyne's answer on that post
4. It's not working.
What is wrong and what should I do? When I configure it correctly, URL will be fine.

Comment: You question says you are generating a URL for images `http://localhost:8080/my_company/profile_pictures/admin1/admin1.jpg`. This doesn't fit with you configuration `registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**")` which as I understand it will serve images at the url beginning with `http://localhost:8080/{appname}/images/...`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood from this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289571/how-to-display-files-from-external-folder-with-spring-boot-2-1-1

Answer (score 0):

Add in your `application.properties`

```
spring.resources.static-locations = classpath:/static/,file:///C:/my_company/profile_pictures/
```

assume your file name is `user.jpg` into this location **C:/my_company/profile_pictures/**

so you can access directly by calling `http://localhost:8080/user.jpg`

finally you can customize your path or **URL** as you want depending on the `base path and directory as well as file name`.